# Connect to remote after openvpn start

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn

I have a remote vps amazon ec2. I want to use openvpn client on it. Openvpn runs successfully but I can't connect to it through ssh.

```
(remote vps) <–––––> through vpn <–––> some remote sites(many ips)
   ^                 (this works)
   |              
   | (can't connect)
   |
(my pc)
```

How can I connect to remote vps when openvpn client is running there?

`client.conf`

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpnserver.com 1198
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass auth.txt
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.rsa.2048.pem
ca ca.rsa.2048.crt
disable-occ
```